Unbiased Variance MLE Distribution
If you take $10000$ samples from a normal distribution, the unbiased variance MLE (with Bessel's correction) is
$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{9999}\sum_i (x_i - \hat{\mu})$$
Apparently the distribution of $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is right skewed? How could one know or derive this?

Several errors. Better would be to say $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_i (x_i - \bar x)^2$ is an unbiased estimator of the variance, but the maximum likelihood estimator is $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_i (x_i - \bar x)^2$.  Both have distributions proportional to a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution and so have skewness $\sqrt{8 /(n-1)}$ which is positive, i.e. right-skewed, but only slightly for large $n$.

As requested in comments:
It would be better to say $\frac{1}{n−1}\sum\limits_i(X_i−\bar X)^2$ (with Bessel's correction) is an unbiased estimator of the variance, while the maximum likelihood estimator (which does not have Bessel's correction) is $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_i(X_i−\bar X)^2$.
Both have distributions proportional to a $\chi^2_{n−1}$ distribution and so have skewness $\sqrt{8/(n−1)}$, which is positive, i.e. right-skewed, but only slightly for large $n$.
